# Can I route add automatically when a network interface is added?

Tags: macos, network, automation

Every morning, I connect my MacBook to my company network with the Apple USB Ethernet Adapter:

[image]

Then open the `Terminal` to add routes in order to access intranet servers:

```
 $ sudo route add -net 192.168.21.0/24 192.168.8.8
 $ sudo route add -net 192.168.22.0/24 192.168.8.8
 $ sudo route add -net 192.168.23.0/24 192.168.8.8
```

Is there a way that triggered by a new network interface (with a certain name) is added, then auto run the above `route add` commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sidekick will do this for you: http://oomphalot.com/sidekick/